# Softlayer API storage offers with prices

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to gather information about storage offers from SoftLayer using SoftLayer API. There are different categories of storage in SoftLayer, for example: object, block and file storages.

According to this page https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you I should use `client["SoftLayer_Product_Package"].getItems(id=206)`
but for object storage it returns a list of two items without prices. According to SoftLayer web site there should be much more offers than only two;)

I found somewhere information that I should use this `client['Product_Package'].getObjectStorageDatacenters(id=206)`
and it works but only for objects storage. When using ids of other storage packages I get empty results.

How can I get offers with prices for block and file storage packages?

Answer (score 1):

Softlayer has many packages, each package has items for a determinated product, the package that you are seeing is only for object storage, for block storage and file storages the package is different, try to use the package 759 or 222. In order to get the list of all available packages see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_product_package/getallobjects

Comment: Thank you for your help. Package 222 contains performance block storage offers. 
Package 759 contains many offers, some of them I can easily match with endurance block storage offers but others I can not match with any offers from block storage. For example offer with id 9587 and description "100 - 6000 IOPS". Do you know where can I find those offers on web site with prices?

Comment: yep that is the IOPS section when you are ordening a block storage of type performance, In web says "Specify IOPSEnter between 100 and 6000 by intervals of 100 as determined by your selection above"